# angular : 7 How test child emitter on parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Write test case for event emitter. Write test case for `modelopen()` method

parent ts file
author-article-carousel.component.ts

```
public edit(row) {
    console.log(row);
    this.activeArticleService.getArticleDetail(row.id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.modalOpen(res);
    });
  }


  public modalOpen(value) {
    let config = {};
    config = {
      disableClose: true,
      maxWidth: '1050px',
      data: { value: value, user: 'author' }
    };
    if (this.dialogRef == null) {
      this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ArticleModalComponent, config);
    }
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog closed: ${result}`);
      this.dialogRef = null;
    });

    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.downloadreport.subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        this.activeArticleService.downloadReport(response).subscribe((response: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
          this.activeArticleService.download(response, 'report.pdf');
        });
      }
    });
}
```

parent HTML file
author-article-carousel.component.html

```
<prism-article-carousel
  (clickOnTitle)="edit($event)"
></prism-article-carousel>
```

child HTML file
article-carousel.component.html

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <a (click)="edit(item)" class="mat-card-title" style="cursor: pointer">{{ item.title }}</a>
            </div>
```

child ts file
article-modal.component.ts

```
  public downloadReport(url) {
    this.downloadreport.emit(url);
  }
```

Comment: Where exactly is your ```openmodel()``` method triggered? It's neither in your showed parent.html nor child.html.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig -  change code please check again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a working test setup and created a working spy for your activeArticleService

There are two approaches depending on whether you are using a shallow test or actually have setup a test where all the components are declared. (I would suggest using the shallow test approach since it is only a unit test)

Using shallow testing (setting `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`) you can trigger a custom EventHandler by accessing the desired element using:

```
const debugElem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('prism-article-carousel'));
debugElem.triggerEventHandler('clickOnTitle', YOUR_EXPECTED_EVENT_OBJECT)
tick();
```

For this to work your tests needs to use `fakeAsync`.

If you don't use this schema you would get the component instance with

`fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('prism-article-carousel'))`

and you would need something like this (be careful this is only pseudocode)

```
childComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('prism-article-carousel')).componentInstance;
childComponent.emit(YOUR_VALUE_HERE);
tick();
```

Please have a look [here in the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests) for more information on those different approaches to test a nested component.

Comment: Please show what you tried and ideally with a stackblitz that shows and runs the test case how you tried it.